# Modifying regex password checker

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way that I could modify my expression in order to not allow spaces within the password itself?  As of now, it must contain 2 capital, 2 lowercase,2 numbers and can have spaces before and after the password.

```
/^[ ]*((?=(.*\d){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,}).{8,16})[ ]*$/
```

Comment: Removing the `[ ]*` from either end will stop passwords with spaces before and after them. Is that enough, or do you want to stop _any_ space from validating the password? Also, don't forget to validate this server-side, too.

Comment: @JamWaffles, The spaces on either side of the password were intentional,  I'm asking if there is a way to prevent spaces from within the password.  And yes I know :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[\s]*((?=([^\s]*\d){2,})(?=([^\s]*[a-z]){2,})(?=([^\s]*[A-Z]){2,})[^\s]{8,16})[\s]*$/
```